# Visual Force Page Error in salesforce

Tags: visualforce

I have Written the Visual Force Page Coding :

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Back"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="sampleGrid" value="{!Contact.AccountId}" var="a">
                    <apex:inputfield label="Account"  value="{!Contact.AccountId}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

output:
 **it is Showing only one Grid line , but it is Not Displaying the lookupField on the Visual Force Page, How to Rectify the Error, Anyone Guide Me for the Answer**

Comment: Your code is messy. Do you want to display one record or a list of records?

Comment: I want to display the Lookup field Label in visual force page How

Comment: Just replace your <apex:pageBlockTable> section with a single <apex:inputfield label="Account"  value="{!Contact.AccountId}" />. It will be working

Comment: I guess pageblock table always use list os sobject or wrapper not the single field like above `Contact.AccountId`

Comment: @Ratan single field is Not  possible in apex Page block Table

Comment: yeah so how come this is possible `<apex:pageBlockTable id="sampleGrid" value="{!Contact.AccountId}" var="a">`?

Comment: @Ratan how to display the Grid with the single Value Field in apex page block table

Comment: why pageblocktable? I guess you need to use pageblocksectionitem with single column

Comment: @Ratan How to display the list of Sobject Records in apex page Block Table

Comment: list of sobject in pageblocktable with single column ?

Comment: Ratan i want to Display the lookup filed on the apex page block table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44145/discussion-between-user36188-and-ratan).

Answer (score 1):

The way you use the [`pageBlockTable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm) is little confusing as I see. You have to add `apex:column` tag in order to bring the columns of the table. Try below code for the table. This way you can add more columns to your table.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="sampleGrid" value="{!Contact.AccountId}" var="a">
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Account</apex:facet>
        <apex:inputfield label="Account"  value="{!Contact.AccountId}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

When you use pageBlockTable, the advantage is to bind dynamic values of a list into rows by using the `value` and `var` attribute value. Check the documentation linked. This is not being used in the code anyway. Hope you are in a mid of a development.

Comment: The code will be working. But it doesn't make any sense to use pageBlockTable here.

Comment: Header Name is displaying , how to display lookup field text box is Not showing on the Grid

Comment: Label and Lookup field Value is Not Displaying on the Grid,

Comment: @user36188 : when using `Apex:pageblocktable` , label will not appear, as it is already comes as header of table.